# Is it possible to create a bubble polar chart with Highcharts?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a bubble polar chart with Highcharts, is this possible? Documentation isn't clear about this, and my attempts so far haven't been successful.

It would something look like this:

[image: Example of a bubble polar chart]

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? It's just polar chart with series bubble, see: http://jsfiddle.net/ZYKQG/

```
    series: [{
        type: 'bubble',
        name: 'bubble',
        data: [[100,2,3.3],[45,5,3.2],[225,5,3.1]],
        pointPlacement: 'between'
    }]
```

Comment: Pawel, thank you so much. I've been working with Highcharts for a couple weeks and, for some reason, I wasn't being able to get it to work. Again, thanks a lot